# Redirect to 404 when page does not exist

Tags: php, silex

I need write some code in Silex. I have template, witch tell user when route doesn't exist. How do it in Silex? Maybe somebody faced with it?

Comment: `http_response_code(404);`

Comment: If Silex is a template then that's not where you should handle the 404 error. You need to do that from whatever a controller in the framework you are using.

Comment: [Silex](http://silex.sensiolabs.org) IS actually a framework.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can show a 404 page to your users when the route is not found, like so:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response; 

$app->error(function (\Exception $e, $code) {
    switch ($code) {
        case 404:
            $message = 'The requested page could not be found.';
            break;
        default:
            $message = 'We are sorry, but something went terribly wrong.';
    }

    return new Response($message);
});
```

Obviously replacing the example with your template.

See http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/usage.html#error-handlers

Comment: can you tell me, i am only start learning silex. What i am write in app variable

Comment: `$app` is the application instance you created, most likely using `$app = new Silex\Application();`. We would need to see a code example to help you any further.